# How to calculate $\Gamma(3/4)$ ?

Tags: gamma-function

when i'm using Euler's reflection formula $\Gamma(1/4)$ appears which i'm unable to solve again

Comment: Have a look at https://oeis.org/A068466. It is not rational.

Comment: so it's not possible to have any explicit formula ? @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: The comment in OEIS says its transcendental which would rule out an explicit formula.

Comment: @IanMiller At least not the normal kind of formula.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici The Gamma function of rational numbers tend to include $\pi$ when known, so it should be expected to be irrational either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This PDF is great](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0403510v1.pdf) for finding these values real quick.  Taking a quick look, we have:

$$\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)=2\sqrt[4]\pi\sqrt{K\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)}$$

where $K()$ is an [elliptic integral of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind).

Comment: It is on page 13 if you can't find it easily.

Comment: Thanks for the link ! But take care about how is defined the elliptic integral. Depending on convention it could also be $$\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)=2 \sqrt[4]{\pi } \sqrt{K\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$